# Hide div after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with my code?

After clicking the button, I want to hide and show a `div` with another result.

This is happening, but is not running the submit code. The field value is not getting propagated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#conteudo').hide();

    $('#button').click(function(event){

        $('form#form1').submit(function(event){
            $("#form").hide("slow");
            $("#conteudo").show("slow"); 
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });


    $('#mostrar').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#form").show("show");
        $("#conteudo").hide("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you preventing default? That's why it isn't submitting.

Comment: Are you attempting to refresh just part of the page and do the submit "silently"? If so, you will need more code than this... you'll need to call some sort of AJAX routine to submit the data without the whole page loading the form target. My guess is that's what you're trying to avoid by preventing the submit in the first place, and hiding and showing things doesn't matter if you're going to a whole new page, anyhow.

Comment: Someone could help me?
I'm just doing it with the submit, because when I put this option to hide a div and show another, annulled the command that occurred directly on the form.

Comment: impossible to know nobody do it here. Have helped me with the most difficult things ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding div after submit button pressed - not workin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281926/hiding-div-after-submit-button-pressed-not-workin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to do. If a friend has the same problem solved in this way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#conteudo').hide();

    <?php if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) { ?>
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                event.preventDefault(); 
                $("#form").hide("slow"); 
                $("#conteudo").show("slow"); 
            });
    <?php } ?>

    $('#mostrar').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#form").show("show");
        $("#conteudo").hide("show");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/submit/ says:

> ...so we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the
>   event object or by returning false from our handler. ...

You should remove the preventDefault()

Comment: If I remove the "event.preventDefault()", the submit happens, but does not appear to another div.